# Multi Update A Database Error Occurred Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> I had followed some tutorials to get multi update in codeigniter, but i got a problem, cannot update data.

Error Messege:

A Database Error Occurred
Filename: D:/Coding/Xampp/htdocs/Project/ILC_LUXURY/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1915

this is the controller

```
 $code       = $this->input->post('kd_menu');
    $name       = $this->input->post('nama');
    $katagory   = $this->input->post('katagori');
    $price      = $this->input->post('harga');
    $picture     = $this->input->post('gambar');
    $status     = $this->input->post('status');

    $data = array();
    foreach ((array) $code as $code => $value) {
        $data[] = array(    'kd_menu'       =>   $code,
                            'nama'          =>  $nama[$code],
                            'kd_katagori'   =>   $katagori[$code],
                            'harga'         =>   $harga[$code],
                            'gambar'        =>   $gambar[$code],
                            'status'        =>   $status[$code]

                        );
    }

    $this->db->update_batch('menu', $data,'kd_menu');
```

this is views:

```
<?php               
            $i=1;
            foreach ($menu as $menu ) :  
            ?>                        
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <?php echo $i++?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="kd_menu" value="<?php echo $menu->kd_menu?>">
                              </td>                                  
                              <td>
                                <?php echo $menu->nm_menu?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="nama" value="<?php echo $menu->nm_menu?>">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <?php echo $menu->nama?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="katagori" value="<?php echo $menu->kd_katagori?>">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                Rp. <?php echo number_format($menu->harga,0,',','.')  ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="harga" value="<?php echo $menu->harga?>">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <?php echo $menu->gambar?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="gambar" value="<?php echo $menu->gambar?>">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                              <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                                <option value="1" <?php if($menu->status == "1"){?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Ready</option>
                                <option value="0" <?php if($menu->status == "0"){?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Not Ready</option>
                              </select>                                      
                              </td>
                            </tr>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what is the complete error message? please edit it into your question, thanks

Comment: only that the messege "A Database Error Occurred"

Comment: `foreach ((array) $code as $code => $value) {` ??? proper `foreach` will be `foreach($dataArray as   $key => $value){}`